# Multidirected Graph in NetworkX?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

does anyone know how to make a multidirected graph in NetworkX? My problem is, that the node 3 here does not return to node 2 as I wrote in the edgelist... Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph(directed = True)

G.add_nodes_from(range(1, 11))

edgelist = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 9), (9, 4), (4, 5), (5, 7), (7, 6), (6, 4), (7, 8), (7, 10), (10, 11), (11, 5)]  

G = nx.from_edgelist(edgelist)

nx.draw_networkx(G, 
                 with_labels = True,
                 arrows = True,
                 arrowstyle = '-|>', 
                 node_size = 100,
                 node_color = 'yellow',
                 edge_color = 'black',
                 width = 3,
                 arrowsize = 10)
```

[This is the image I get from this code. There should be two edges on node 2 and 3, but there is just one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCoMH.png)

Comment: `(2, 3), (3, 2)`...this will be a stable point but there is `(3, 9)`  so what are the rules ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `G = nx.from_edgelist(edgelist)` line uses a constructor that replaces the original object, so it's drawing a standard Graph instead of a multidigraph (but still mimics the arrows since forced in the draw-call).

Try replacing that line with `G = nx.from_edgelist(edgelist, create_using = nx.MultiDiGraph())` and you should at least get two arrows drawn on the desired edge. You can also check the output of `nx.info(G)` to verify the graph type in case you're unsure if it worked.

You also don't need the initial variables as the constructor handles that as well. Minimal code to get this working:

```py
import networkx as nx

edgelist = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 9), (9, 4), (4, 5), (5, 7), (7, 6), (6, 4), (7, 8), (7, 10), (10, 11), (11, 5)]  

G = nx.from_edgelist(edgelist, create_using = nx.MultiDiGraph())

nx.draw_networkx(G, 
                 with_labels = True,
                 arrows = True,
                 arrowstyle = '-|>', 
                 node_size = 100,
                 node_color = 'yellow',
                 edge_color = 'black',
                 width = 3,
                 arrowsize = 10)
```

Comment: this seems to work, thanks :) the edges look now a bit unorganized, but i'll try to find a way for that